# handling multiple click events , if all are under single div which is clickable

Tags: angular, angular7

I am working with Angular Project

1. I have Implemented mat card that is clickable
2. In that card there are two buttons

eg

```
<div mat-card (click)='details()'>
   <input placeholder='enter name'>
   <button (click)='submit()> Submit </button>
   <button (click)='cancel()> Cancel </button>

</div>
```

ts

```
details(){}
submit(){}
cancel(){}
```

**How to handle all the three function**

Comment: one approach, would be to pass in `$event` to the click handler and check its `.target`. in your case this is only required in your `details()` handler.

Comment: you can use `$event.stopPropagation()` with click function. checkout this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqz2ve)

Answer (score 3):

Since you have set a click listener for your `mat-card` which in your case is the parent, any children under your parent will also trigger the click event of the parent. You need to stop the parent's click being triggered when the child element is clicked. You have to use `$event.stopPropogation` in order to achieve that.

**html**

```
<mat-card class="example-card" (click)="detail()">
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Title</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <button (click)="submit();$event.stopPropagation();">Submit</button>
    <button (click)="cancel();$event.stopPropagation();">Cancel</button>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

**ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  submit(){
    console.log('submit');
  }

  cancel(){
    console.log('cancel');
  }

  detail(){
    console.log('detail');
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome!!!!!!!!